# What is the underlying theme in OSGi?

Tags: osgi

OSGi is a dynamic modular system for Java. Ok, but what is the base line theme, why was OSGi  developed? What are the benifits of using OSGi? What is the main story of developing OSGi? Why does it exist?

Comment: osgi is a way that says, "hey we know ya'll programmers have bad habits, but here's a way to make it easier to practice your bad habits."

Answer (score 17):

If you look closer, the concept of classpath in Java really sucks.

You distribute your classes in JAR files, but during runtime Java will (almost) blindly throw all the classes from all the JAR files into one big bag where classes with the same name overshadow each other and then interact in unexpected ways.

OSGi brings a proper runtime modularity to Java platform and on top of that a powerful service model, sometimes referred to as "SOA inside the JVM".

I would strongly recommend reading some introductory articles about OSGi that will give a more concrete idea of what this all means. A good starting point might be the series of articles on InfoQ about Java modularity by Alex Blewitt:

- [Modular Java: What Is It?](http://www.infoq.com/articles/modular-java-what-is-it)
- [Modular Java: Static Modularity](http://www.infoq.com/articles/modular-java-static-modularity)
- [Modular Java: Dynamic Modularity](http://www.infoq.com/articles/modular-java-dynamic-modularity)

Answer (score 5):

[OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/About/Technology) is

- A module system for Java: it provides a way of exporting and importing Java packages and enforcing the module boundaries, including explicit dependency and version information.
- A generalized container for Java systems: bundles can be dynamically loaded and unloaded without stopping the system, where "bundle" is basically jar file.
- A service-oriented programming system: in addition to modularizing the system by packages, OSGi supports service-oriented modularity, including things like the [whiteboard pattern](http://www.osgi.org/wiki/uploads/Links/whiteboard.pdf) (PDF).

OSGi was originally developed to support high-end embedded systems such as set-top boxes, which motivates the explicit dependencies and versioning, as well as making it fairly lightweight when used as a  more recent, enterprise-side container.

Comment: Before the OSGi Alliance renamed itself, OSGi stood for "Open Services  Gateway Initiative". It's main target were embedded home gateways and routers.

Answer (score 4):

whatever benefits OSGi offers, they are overshadowed by the loss in flexibility, the modifications to the build environment and a host of other changes, mostly caused by (highly experienced) developer incompetence.

These impediments will decrease developer productivity and therefore decrease the speed with which all improvements to the sourcecode can be made (not just modularity improvements).

Comment: I don't agree, the tooling around Bundles is quite good, so it can do a lot itself (Bnd and Felix Annotations and you cover quite a lot). And a lot of open source libraries already have OSGi manifest entries (exactly because it is rather easy to add).

Comment: Examples: Maven bundle plugins generating config files rejected by Felix as malformed (and having to fix them by hand), "Apply to classpath" which breaks maven projects, no errors or warnings when something fails to work,  boilerplate up the wazoo, iPOJO silently fails to do its job, misspellings in messages, requires hacking (pax url) to make work the same between IDE and deployed JAR because they over-designed it and assumed that every machine is going to have an admin controlling an OSGi container, making deployment of pluggable games, graphics, audio software to normal users unreasonable.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the question can be reduced to 'What is the value of Modularisation'. For an excellent series of articles on this subject by Kirk Knoernschild see http://techdistrict.kirkk.com/. I believe a book is also in the works.

If you are academically inclined - the power of modularity and dynamic system assembly are well explored by a recently published book - "Diversity and Complexity" (http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9208.html). Though not software centric - the book explains why the next generation of adaptive / robust software system will have to be modular.

Note that, in addition to being the industry standard for Java Modularity (so enabling all of the above); OSGi also brings to the table a powerful 'SOA-inside the JVM' Services architecture.

Finally, for a gentle and well crafted introduction to developing in OSGi - try Neil Bartlett's book 'OSGi in Practise' http://njbartlett.name/osgibook.html

Regards

Richard